# Spring Boot "redirect:/path" doesn't work - actually returning the String "redirect:/path"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to redirect from one my controllers to another controller. It should work with the keyword "redirect", but instead of redirecting to he other controller, I'm getting this response:

[image: response]

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@Api(value = ConsentConstants.GET_HEALTH_V1, tags = {ConsentConstants.SWAGGER_API})
@Slf4j
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class GetHealthController implements GetHealthApi {

  final Tracer tracer;

  @Override
  public Object getHealthCheck() {
    return "redirect:/actuator/health";
  }
}
```

The reason I'm trying the redirect is because the healthcheck (spring boot actuator) is not working when I deploy my service. Locally it works fine, but after deployment I receive a 401 unauthorized for the /actuator/health endpoint (the other endpoints work fine). So I wanted to try to use one of the working endpoints (e.g. status/health and then redirect to /actuator/health)

I'm not using Spring MVC, is that's making any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way of redirecting only works for regular controllers, not a rest service. There is no way to resolve a 'view' named **/actuator/health**.

This only works when there is a view with a filename of registration to resolve:

```java
return "redirect:registration";
```

To redirect in a restcontroller, you can do something like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/healthcheck")
public void getHealthCheck(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  response.sendRedirect("/actuator/health");
}
```

However, if you just want to change the health endpoint of Spring actuator it is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path).

In application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/whatever
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
```

Comment: However, I do not think this will help your case, as you will just be redirected to your previous point of failure. I think something else is preventing you from reaching the endpoint. I can't really tell what just from what is described in your question though.

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("/actuator/health")` worked, thanks.
I tried `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/whatever
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck` before, there was some problem because the healthcheck is also used by our deployment environment to check if the service is still up.